# How to install package fOptions?

Tags: r

I'm trying to install the package fOptions but got the error:

```
> library(fOptions)
Error in library(fOptions) : there is no package called ‘fOptions’
```

Comment: Have you installed it? `install.packages("fOptions")`? Then you can use `library(fOptions)`.

Comment: Thank you Ananda                                                  Is this Warning message important?:
package ‘fOptions’ was built under R version 3.0.2

Comment: I believe that warning is usually displayed if there is a mismatch between the version of R you are running and the version for which the package was built. It is there to indicate that there *might* be some problems (but generally not unless the newer version of R has underwent a major enough change to break backwards compatibility).

Comment: @AnandaMahto I took the liberty to transform your correct comment into an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The `library` function is used to load packages, not to install them. To install a package, you need to use `install.packages("fOptions")`. See `?library` and `?install.packages` for more details.