# How to install gdata in R?

Tags: r

I am totally new for installing outer tools or libraries into R.
I want to use gdata tool in R, which is outer tools so needed to install.

From this page, 
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gdata/index.html
I downloaded  windows binaries(because my PC is 64bit windows) 
1)but I don't know how to install this in my PC after this.
inside gdata folder there are so many files but none of these are installation file! What should I do??? Nowhere can I find installation guide...
2)And how to call functions inside this file on R.
Could you please help me? Many Thanks!

Comment: You can't do `install.packages("gdata")` from the R console? You might want to read `?install.packages` thoroughly.

Comment: Install the package as Richard describes and then load the package with `library("gdata")`

Comment: Surprisingly, I could not find a duplicate for "how to install an R package" ...although it seems like there should be hundreds.

Comment: This is easy using Rstudio: go `tools` -> `install packages...`. Type `gdata` in the box, et voila.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install package fOptions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602952/how-to-install-package-foptions)

Answer (score 5):

`install.packages("gdata")`

`require(gdata)`

If that gives you any trouble try:

`install.packages("master.tar.gz", type = "source", repos = NULL)`

where `"master.tar.gz"` is the file you downloaded. Specify the path with double (escaped) backslashes if it is not in your working directory.

I wrote "Master" to correspond to source downloaded from GitHub (i.e. the "Master branch") but the name from CRAN will be different.